# concatenate with ISBLANK and delimiter

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, concatenation, space, blank

I am attempting to combine two columns in Excel 2016, with a space between the results. My problem is being able to use `ISBLANK` to ignore blanks on either column, and still have the space delimiter in the final result when two fields are combined.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data in columns A and B and if you only want a space if there is data in both columns, then something like this will work.

```
=A1&IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<>"")," ","")&B1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try TEXTJOIN function:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1,B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lee, but TEXTJOIN is not available in my Excel 2016 version.